# What is used for the % symbol in mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, functions, numerics, units, numerical-value

Im new in mathematica i want to know logic about this program. I got this code:

{{vo, vn, Ii}} = {vo, vn, Ii} /. %;

i know that the syntax /. is for replacement but i dont know whats going on  with %

pls help me

Comment: see [Out (%)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Out.html) in the docs.

Comment: See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616

Comment: I believe this is `ans` in matlab, or `_` in python, or `%` in maple, etc.